# F# Fork pipe

Tags: f#

I have the following (working) bit of code:

```
let a = 
    File.ReadAllLines("C:\ColorTable.dat")
    |> Array.filter (fun i -> i.StartsWith(" "))
    |> Array.iter (fun i -> 
        Console.WriteLine(@"ColorList.Add({0}, ""{1}"");", extract_num i, extract_col i)
        f.WriteLine(@"ColorList.Add({0}, ""{1}"");", extract_num i, extract_col i)
        )
```

The functions extract_num and extract_col apply a regex to the line of the file and extract part of it. Then I print a formatted string to the console *and* to a file.

To do this I write the formatted part twice. What is a more clean way of doing this? I could define a function to accept extract_num and extract_col that return the formatted string and call it twice, of course, but, for the sake of learning, what is the most *functional* way of doing this?

Out of my mind, could I output the formatted string both to the Console and to the file with some sort of pipe forking?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Here's some code...

```
open System.IO
let ComposeTextWriters (tws:TextWriter[]) =
    { new TextWriter() with 
        override this.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.Default 
        override this.Write(c:char) =
            tws |> Array.iter (fun tw -> tw.Write(c)) }

let data = [(1,1); (2,2); (3,3)]

[<EntryPoint>]
let Main(_) =
    use fileToWrite = new StreamWriter(File.OpenWrite("out.txt")) :> TextWriter
    let stdout = System.Console.Out 
    let compositeOut = ComposeTextWriters [|fileToWrite;stdout|]
    data |> List.iter (fun (x,y) ->
        compositeOut.WriteLine("{0}: '{1}'", x, y))
    0
```

I don't know if this is a great way to do this, but it seems to work.  ComposeTextWriters takes as input an array of TextWriters and returns a new TextWriter that writes all output to all of them.  Is this the kind of thing you're looking for?

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding the question, the "fork pipe" you're asking for might look like

```
let fork f g x = (f x); (g x);
```

And you could use it like this:

```
let extract i = sprintf "ColorList.Add(%A \"%A\")" (extract_num i) (extract_col i)

File.ReadAllLines("C:\ColorTable.dat")
   |> Array.filter (fun s -> s.StartsWith(" "))
   |> Array.iter (extract >> fork Console.WriteLine f.WriteLine);
```

(Based on code from dahlbyk's answer)

Answer (score 0):

I would factor out your logic to extract and print values into their own functions. Also, your `a` will always be `unit` - I suspect you might actually want to save the values you're producing to use elsewhere. I might rewrite your code something like this:

```
let a = 
    let extract_values s = (extract_num s),(extract_col s)
    let print_values (num,col) =
        let msg = sprintf "ColorList.Add(%A \"%A\")" num col
        Console.WriteLine(msg)
        f.WriteLine(msg)
        num,col
    File.ReadAllLines("C:\ColorTable.dat")
    |> Array.filter (fun s -> s.StartsWith(" "))
    |> Array.map extract_values
    |> Array.map print_values
```

`a` would be an array of the `num,col` pairs.

If you don't actually care about the extracted values, you could instead return a string and pass it directly into `print`:

```
let extract_values s =
    sprintf "ColorList.Add(%A \"%A\")" (extract_num s) (extract_col s)
let print_values (s : string) =
    Console.WriteLine(s)
    f.WriteLine(s)
File.ReadAllLines("C:\ColorTable.dat")
|> Array.filter (fun s -> s.StartsWith(" "))
|> Array.map extract_values
|> Array.iter print_values
```